# 'initial' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

i'm Getting this error "'initial' is an invalid keyword argument for this function", I'm trying to create an object by a createview, what is this error and why am I getting it ?

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^add/$', views.CriarTrabalhador.as_view(), name='add')]
```

---

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.

    class Trabalhadores(models.Model):
        Nome = models.CharField('Name',max_length=100)
        Cpf = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=11)
        Data = models.DateField('Data de Nascimento')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.Nome
```

---

**forms.py**

```
   from django import forms
   from .models import Trabalhadores

    class TrabalhadoresForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
           model = Trabalhadores
                fields = ["Nome","Cpf","Data"]
```

---

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import Trabalhadores
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView,CreateView
from . import forms

class CriarTrabalhador(CreateView):
    model = Trabalhadores
    form_class = forms.Trabalhadores
    template_name = 'mytemp/adicionartrabalhador.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('trabalhadores')
```

edit

After submiting the form, I'm getting this url

localhost/add/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=PVjqYnZNwJZpHuObu1OXNSnIekeqMVVeNIIxTkr2UFH7ii83QScfGdBrX5HjmZCe&Nome=test&Cpf=00000000000&Data=1998-12-14

Why is that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've set the form_class in that view to be Trabalhadores, which is the model, instead of TrabalhadoresForm, which is the form.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, but now when submitting the form I get an strange url, thanks, I edited my post.

Comment: You must not have set `method='POST'` in the form element in your template.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your form_class is equals to your form

Like form_class =TrabalhadoresForm , because you are creating view using your from class and data will be pass through your model class
Same for all type of Django generic class view